# C# converter Array para inserção no banco

Tags: c#, array

Tenho um `Array`, alguns dos valores desse array será adicionado como `float` outros como `int`, minha duvida é a seguinte, como eu posso converter apenas um array não a lista toda?

Eu teria que criar uma variável para receber esse valor e converter? ou teria um jeito mais simples?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string procurar = "|";
        int Converter;
        StreamReader Arquivo = new StreamReader(@"C:\log\meutxt.txt");
        string[] arrValores = new string[48]; //48
        SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(@"Password=Azeite10;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=bdTeste;Data Source=DESKTOP-G8JGBNC");/*@"Password=Azeite10;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=bdTeste;Data Source=SCAN-D-50985\SQL"*/
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conexao;
        conexao.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Carregando...");
        while (Arquivo.Peek() != -1)
        {
            var strLinha = Arquivo.ReadLine().Split('|');

            arrValores[0] = strLinha[1];
            arrValores[1] = strLinha[2];
            arrValores[2] = strLinha[3];
            arrValores[3] = strLinha[4];



            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO [dbo].[123] VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')", strLinha[1], strLinha[2], strLinha[3], strLinha[4].ToString());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
```

o meu arquivo de texto no processo final me retorna uma linha assim.

```
|2021549040    |000001                     |0001                    |MTO                       |ZXDC            |5034293         |ASIAN AMERICAN METALS, INC.        |5034293               |ASIAN AMERICAN METALS, INC.        |6126585         |LPL 3003 H14 1,600X1219,2X3048 C-CC-EE  |PO343610 - BALTIMORE               |        23,859 |KG            |      23.859,000 |        23.859,000 |         0,000 |Z)            |               29.217,000 |                   0,000 |                  0,000 |       0,000 |22.12.2017        |2020       |C              |18.04.2018|27.07.2018        |27.07.2018     |26.07.2018         |27.07.2018           |             |2200                 |OUTROS ME      |LCC01001         |CC ME                         |                    |                           |               |Laminados         |BANACM       |          |                                    |CIP-BALTIMORE                 |               0,000 |                             |2020              |
```

aonde o | "CONTEUDO"   | representa uma coluna do arquivo de texto original

Tabelas no banco de dados

```
[dbo].[1234]
       ([Ordem de venda]
       ,[Item do documento de vendas]
       ,[N. da divisão de remessa]
       ,[Estratégia]
       ,[Tipo Doc. Vendas]
       ,[Emissor da Ordem]
       ,[Nome do Cliente]
       ,[Cód. Receb. Mercadoria]
       ,[Receb. Mercadoria]
       ,[Cód. do Material]
       ,[Desc. do Material]
       ,[N. Pedido do Cliente]
       ,[Qtde Item Ordem]
       ,[Unidade Medida]
       ,[Qtde Item Divisão]
       ,[Quantidade Faturada]
       ,[Saldo a faturar]
       ,[Ctg de Divisão]
       ,[Quantidade Produzida (MTO)]
       ,[Qtd. em Estoque (Fábrica)]
       ,[Estoque para Centro (CD)]
       ,[Estoque (901)]
       ,[Data de criação OV]
       ,[Centro (CD)]
       ,[Status da Ordem]
       ,[Data GRD]
       ,[1ª. Data Prometida]
       ,[Data de Entrega]
       ,[Data prep. material]
       ,[Data saída mercadoria]
       ,[Motivo Recusa]
       ,[Organização de Vendas]
       ,[Cta. no Cliente]
       ,[Vlr.Fam.Orçamento]
       ,[Desc.Fam.Orçamento]
       ,[Observação]
       ,[Cod.Fixação Ordem Planejada]
       ,[Lista de anexos]
       ,[Desc.Fam.Expedição]
       ,[Criador da OV]
       ,[Itinerário]
       ,[Descrição do transito]
       ,[INCOTERMS]
       ,[Quantidade em remessa]
       ,[Comprimento]
       ,[Local de expedição])
```

Comment: Esse código não faz sentido, é extremamento inseguro e a pergunta não dá detalhes suficientes para dar uma resposta adequada, inclusive cita coisas que não dá para perceber no código. Precisa melhorar a pergunta pata entendermos o problema.

Comment: simples meu array recebe 48 linhas, tenho que inserir esses dados no banco de dados, porem preciso converter alguns para float ou date, pois sem converter o sql não insere no banco, coloquei meu código inteiro, não está completo ainda, está lista arrValores[ vai até 48]

Comment: Você poderia colocar o layout do arquivo de texto e os campos da sua base de dados?

Comment: editei minha pergunta com essas informações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guilherme, alterei o seu código da forma abaixo para realizar a tarefa e resolver a questão das conversões.

Modifiquei a sua query para passar a utilizar parâmetros.

No loop, é definido os valores dos parâmetros, com suas respectivas conversões de tipo, considerando que o layout das linhas do seu arquivo, no que diz respeito ao tipo de cada coluna, é sempre o mesmo.

Note que no código abaixo utilizei apenas 5 campos, para simplificar o exemplo.

Com esta implementação você consegue aplicar as conversões sem a necessidade de criar variáveis para armazenar os dados.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class Program
{    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader Arquivo = new StreamReader(@"C:\log\meutxt.txt");

        SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(@"Password=Azeite10;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=bdTeste;Data Source=DESKTOP-G8JGBNC");/*@"Password=Azeite10;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=bdTeste;Data Source=SCAN-D-50985\SQL"*/
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conexao;
        conexao.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Carregando...");

        // Definição da query que será executada.
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[123] VALUES (@par1, @par2, @par3, @par4, @par5)";

        while (Arquivo.Peek() != -1)
        {
            var strLinha = Arquivo.ReadLine().Split('|');

            // Limpa a lista de parâmetros para nova definição destes a cada iteração, uma vez que os valores dos parâmetros sofrerão alterações.
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@par1", Convert.ToDouble(strLinha[1])); // Campo do tipo Double.
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@par2", Convert.ToInt32(strLinha[2]));  // Campo do tipo Int.
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@par3", Convert.ToInt32(strLinha[3]));
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@par4", strLinha[4]);                   // Campo do tipo String. Não requer conversão pois strLinha já é do tipo string.
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@par5", strLinha[5]);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        conexao.Close();
    }
}
```

Caso a solução acima não lhe atenda, nos informe para tentarmos ajudar novamente.

Comment: exatamente oque eu necessitava, muito obrigado!